# Solve equation $\exp(ax)+\exp(bx)=1$

Tags: exponential-function, transcendental-equations

The equation is
$$
\exp\left(ax\right)+\exp\left(bx\right)=1,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are known real constants, $x$ is unknown.
I would like to have the solution in form of relatively known special function (something like Lambert $W$ function, or generalized hyper-geometric $F$).

Comment: Since this is (up to logarightms) equivalent to solving $$y^a + y^b = 1,$$ I'm not sure if this is even doable. At least in a closed form.

Comment: If $a=0$ or $b=0$, there is no solution. 
If $a<0$ and $b>0$, and $(-a/b)^{a/(b-a)}+(-a/b)^{b/(b-a)}>1$, there is no solution.
Could you tell us more about the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @V.Rossetto, it is assumed that there is solution, and $a$ and $b$ are appropriate. My question is about functions, or about the proof that there is no constructive way to explicitly define the function of a and b such that $F(a,b)$ is the solution to the equation.

Answer (score 6):

If we place $y=\exp(x)$ we can rewrite the problema as:
$$y^a+y^b=1$$
Such trinomial equation is a particular case of more general:
$$y^a+z y^b=1$$ where we have supposed $a>b$.
The solution of the trinomial equation can be found by means of Lagrange inversion series or also by Mellin transform as:
$$y(a,b,z)=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{r=0}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+rb}{a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+rb}{a}+1-r\right)r!}(-1)^rz^r$$
So $$x(a,b)=\log\left[\frac{1}{a}\sum_{r=0}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+rb}{a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+rb}{a}+1-r\right)r!}(-1)^r\right]$$
**References**

"The Functions of Mathematical Physics ", 1986, Harry Hochstadt

** EDITED to fix several typos **

Comment: Is it consistent @bassam-karzeddin formulae when $a$ and $b$ are integer?

Comment: I have some reason to believe that @bassam-karzeddin rediscovered the series of Mellin to solve trinomial equations.

Comment: Adding some explanation of why you have that belief e.g. a solution for 0 would be very helpful...

Comment: Just saying such that then it would be slightly easier to adjust for testing to lessen any bias...Other spaces and theories (manifolds etc) aside I am just visualizing that it would be easier to apply for such given the starting point of 0... :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new special and multivalued function called Lambert-Tsallis, where you can find details about it at "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications 525, 164-170", or to get in contact with a friend and coworker R. V. Ramos.

As mentioned before, your problem can be written like
$$y^a + y^b = 1$$.

If you choose $C_1= ln(b/a)$ and $C_2=ln(a)$ and making $C=C_2/C_1$ you will find

$$ y=\left[ C\cdot W_{\frac{1-C}{C}}\left(\frac{1}{C}\right) \right]^\frac{1}{C_1} 
         (1)$$

It must be emphasized that $W_q(x)$ is a multi-valued function and it will generate complex numbers. The manipulations used to arrive at Eq(1) consider that you have to ignore the complex roots and to get only the real roots.
Also,  the same care with exponentiation!
At the end, maybe you want to know the real values of $y$. In this way, you have to calculate all values of $y$ and to get only those reals! It works. Let me give you an example.
$$Ex_1:  a=4, b=17 $$

it will generate to $W_q(x)$ function the values
$$-5.891953651234767 - 0.568776496431273i,  -5.891953651234591 + 0.568776496431205i, $$
$$ -2.263956382339662 - 2.956616138268131i,  -2.263956382339578 + 2.956616138268151i,$$
$$  1.184097200785913 - 0.000000000000043i$$

and the final solution $y$ as
$$  1.018598506148727 - 0.243077842499787i, 1.018598506148725 + 0.243077842499787i$$
$$  0.995769093645394 - 0.172057290937165i, 0.995769093645393 + 0.172057290937163i$$
$$  0.925272251271377 - 0.000000000000003i$$
where **the only correct result is** the last one. It happens because you have to ignore since the beginning (for this specific of problem) the complex roots generated by $W_q(x)$

$$Ex_2:  a=\pi, b=e^1 .$$ I use these numbers only to support the potencial of $W_q(x)$ function. $ W_q$  result is -0.148963736984781 - 0.000000000000020i and the final solution is $y= 0.788988678082841 - 0.000000000000249i$

Comment: @ K Z Nobrega Could you please combine your two answers to one answer? They seem belong to the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "a" and "b" are not zero, this equation does not have any explicit solution except if, say, "b" is a multiple of "a".

So, for the general case, this equation would be solved using a root-finder method such as Newton. What is nice is that, knowing the values of "a" and "b", a reasonably good guess of the solution can be easily made.

If you want to see that working, just give me the "a" and "b" you want and I shall post the path to solution for you.

Comment: I really wonder why a downvote !

Comment: You claimed something without proof: "this equation does not have any explicit solution"

Comment: @Gaffney. Do you think we need to prove this ? I said that if the ratio of $a$ to $b$ is an integer, things "could" be done. Cheers.

Comment: It's enough for the ratio to be rational.

Comment: @Lucian.You are right.

Comment: @Gaffney: Regarding your complaint: Mr. Leibovici has discovered a truly marvellous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain. - You happy now ? :-|

Comment: @Lucian. Suppose we face $7 a = 31 b$. How, what shall we do ? I am just curious to know how we should have an explicit solution. Please, give me your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Then our equation becomes $y^{31}+y^{7}-1=0$, where $y=e^{kx}$, for some unspecified *k*. Of course, the solution may not be expressibel in radicals, but we know that (at least some) algebraics can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions (see [Bring radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), for instance, as well as this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582825/are-elementary-and-generalized-hypergeometric-functions-sufficient-to-express-al)), and our OP allowed for such. Then we further extract *x* as $\frac1k\ln y$, for some *k*.

Answer (score 1):

Now, getting back to the original problem
$$ e^{ax} + e^{bx} =1    \hspace{1cm} (1)$$
If one consider $y=e^x$ at Eq.(1) it could rewritten as
$$ y^{a} + y^{b} =1    \hspace{1cm} (2)$$
whose solution was previously given. Thus, the general solution for $x$ will be given by

$$x=\frac{1}{C_1}\cdot ln\left[ C \cdot W_{\frac{1-C}{C}}\left( \frac{1}{C} \right) \right] \hspace{1cm} (3)$$
$Ex_1$ : consider $a=4, b=7.5$, the $W_q(x)$ will produce the result $0.565629288701988 + 0.000000000000003i$ which will give
$$ x =  -0.124652854199031 + 0.000000000000002i$$

$Ex_2$ : One interesting set of numbers arise when $b=2a$ ($a=3,b=6$, **for example**). In this case, one has $W_0(1)$ as argument of natural logarithm  which generates the roots
$$  -1.618033988749864 - 0.000000000000005i, $$
$$ 0.618033988749858 - 0.000000000000032i$$
Indeed, the analytical results correspond to $x= -\left( \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)$, it means, $-1$ multiplying the 2 golden numbers that have the property $-a_- =\frac{1}{a_+}$. Thus, this equation truly has infinity analytic solutions given by
$$ x_1= \frac{1}{C_1}\cdot \left[ ln(a_+) + i(2k+1)\pi \right]$$
$$ x_2= -\frac{1}{C_1}\cdot ln(a_+) $$
In our example, getting the results generating by Lambert-Tsallis function, $W_q(x)$, we have obtained
$$   0.160403941686528 - 1.047197551196597i$$
$$ -0.160403941686554 - 0.000000000000017i$$
The imaginary part of the firs solution is $\pi/3$ because for the numbers used $C_1=3$. If one considers to change only this factor for $\pm \pi/3, \pm 3\pi/3, \pm 5\pi/3$ and so on, the number will be solution of Eq. (1) yet

Answer (score 0):

Suppose without loss of generality, that $a=1$ and $b<1$ and set $y=\mathrm e^{x}$, with $0<y<1$.

- **If** $b<0$, the minimum of $x\mapsto x+x^b$ for $x\in]0,+\infty[$ is
  $$(-b)^{\frac1{1-b}}+\left(-b\right)^{\frac b{1-b}}=(-b)^{\frac1{1-b}}+\left(\frac1{-b}\right)^{\frac{-b}{1-b}}>1,$$
  because if $b\neq-1$ either $-b$ or $-1/b$ is larger than 1. If $b=-1$ this minimum obviously equals $2$.
  There is no solution.
- **If** $b=0$, as $\mathrm e^x+1>1$, there is no solution either.
- **If** $0<b<1$, the function $y\mapsto 1-y^{b}$ is a decreasing function on $[0,1]$. The equation rewrites $y+y^{b}=1$ or
  $$ y=1-y^{b}.\tag{1}$$
  Thus the solution is of the form $$x(b)=\ln f(b),$$
  where $f(b)$ is the fixed point of $y\mapsto 1-y^b$ in $]0,1[$.$$ $$
  An algorithm to find the numerical value of $x(b)$: define $z_0\in]0,1[$ and compute the values of $z_n=1-z_{n-1}^b$ for $n\geq 1$. Then the sequence $(z_n)_n$ converges towards $f(b)$.

As it is said in the comments to your questions, even for several values of  $b\in\mathbf Q\cap]0,1[$, there is no analytic expression for $x(b)$ or $f(b)$, then there is no possibility for finding a function (hypergeometric series, Lambert, etc...) for all $b\in]0,1[$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{ax}+e^{bx}=1\tag{1}$$
$x\to\ln(y)$:
$$y^a+y^b=1\tag{2}$$

For $a,b,x\in\mathbb{N}$, equation (2) is a [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

For rational $a,b$, equation (2) is related to an algebraic equation and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.

For real or complex $a,b\neq 0,1$, equation (2) is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ therefore.

see also: [How to isolate $x$ in $a^x + b^x = c$? (For use in medical statistics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109555/how-to-isolate-x-in-ax-bx-c-for-use-in-medical-statistics/4496115#4496115)

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)