# Explicit solution of the following equation possible?

Tags: transcendental-equations

Is it possible to obtain an explicit solution for $K$ for the following 
equation?

$$(e^K - 1)(e^{\beta K} - 1) = q$$
for $0\leq q \leq 4$ and $0\leq \beta \leq 1$

For $\beta=1$ one gets $K=\log{\left(1+\sqrt{q}\right)}$.

*EDIT*

Actually this equation determines the critical point of the [Potts model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model) on the square lattice with a ratio $\beta$ of horizontal and vertical coupling constants. I was wondering if it is possible to find a transformation of this equation for specific, possibly rational, values of $\beta$, which allows to solve this equation.

Comment: Very unlikely, although I don't have a proof at this time. Note that the equation is equivalent to the (algebraic, when $\beta$ is rational) equation $(u - 1)(u^{\beta} - 1) = q.$

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to obtain an explicit solution for K for the following equation?*

That would depend on the [specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics) value of *q*. For an unspecified *q*, the only $\beta\in[0,1]$ for which an explicit formula $($in terms of [radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem)$)$ exists are $1,\dfrac12$, and $\dfrac13$. Unless you're OK with expressing *K* in terms of [Bring radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) or [hypergeometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582825).